# How to Maintain Customizations Across React Component Releases for Both Functionality and UI Changes?

Tags: reactjs, inheritance

I am developing a React application where end users can customize UI templates, including both UI and functionality changes. These customizations can range from theme adjustments to functional modifications. Currently, when rolling out new releases, we manually transfer these customizations to ensure users do not lose their previous settings, causing delays and increased effort with each release.

Our attempted solution involved using class-based components to allow clients to add new functionalities and override functions. However, this approach falls short when it comes to making changes in the UI according to user preferences.

I have provided a simplified example using class-based components to illustrate the issue. The standard code includes a "Click Me" button with filters for "Filter by Likes" and "Filter by Views." The extended code attempts to add a new filter for date, but it faces limitations in UI customization.

Standard code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Facets extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      likes: false,
      views: false,
    };
  }

  toggleFilter = (filter) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [filter]: !prevState[filter],
    }));
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    console.log("Hello from Facets");
  };

  render() {
    const { likes, views } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
        <h2>Filter Content</h2>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={likes}
            onChange={() => this.toggleFilter('likes')}
          />
          Filter by Likes
        </label>

        <br />

        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={views}
            onChange={() => this.toggleFilter('views')}
          />
          Filter by Views
        </label>

        <div>
          <p>Selected Filters:</p>
          <ul>
            {Object.entries(this.state).map(([filter, isActive]) => (
              isActive && <li key={filter}>{`Filter by ${filter}`}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Facets;
```

[image: Output of Standard Code:]

Extended Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Facets from '../components/facets';

class CustomFacets extends Facets {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      ...this.state,
      date: false,
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    console.log("Hello from CustomFacets");
  };

  render() {
    const { date } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {super.render()}

        <br />

        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={date}
            onChange={() => this.toggleFilter('date')}
          />
          Filter by Date
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomFacets;
```

[image: Output of Extended Code:]

The problem lies in the inability to freely position the custom filter (e.g., "Filter by Date") in the UI. I want to add it below "Filter by Views," but the current approach restricts this flexibility. How can I achieve both functional and UI changes while ensuring compatibility with new releases? I appreciate any insights or alternative approaches to address this challenge.